# Value in a dictionary with ' : ' char

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose key is `external` and a value is `ME:CS`.

How can I reflect the value in a dictionary? I am not sure how to can I reflect a value that has `:` inside the value itself.

I am looking for something like this:

```
dict= {external: ME:CS }
```

Being `external` the key and `ME:CS` the value

Is there any special notation?

Comment: Could it be stored as text? `"ME:CS"`?

Comment: Value is just a string? `"ME:CS"`?

Comment: Are you trying to nest dictionaries? If it is just text, use a string as suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are strings in your dictionary, not raw text. That's the differentiator. Your colon is in quotes, so it's part of the string, rather than a Python syntactic character.

```
{"external": "ME:CS"}
```

EDIT:

If you had wanted the dictionary `{"ME": "CS"}` inside, that's fine, too. It'd look like this:

```
{"external": {"ME": "CS"}}
```